# How to remove or stop a child XMLElement inheriting its Parent's NameSpace

Tags: xml, serialization

I know I can set the namespace for my XmlRoot with the following code:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName:="Requirement", [Namespace]:="http://open-services.net/ns/rm#")>
Public Class Requirement
```

and once my namespaces have been setup, any XmlElements will have namespace prefix set at the root.

But what if I have an XmlElement that does not have a namespace, how can I then remove the namespace?  I know I can change each Element by setting it's namespace:

```
 <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("title", [Namespace]:="http://purl.org/dc/terms/")>
 Public title As String = ""
```

but I can't see a way to remove it, is it possible using the Serialization settings?

Answer (score 0):

I was sure I'd tried this and it didn't work, but just set the `[Namespace]:=""` did it.